# Принципы построения правильного кода PHP

Tags: php

Допустим у нас существует два файла:

- main.php для дальнейшей работы ему необходимо получить текст из файла
- string.php позволяет получить текст из файла

Как вижу я (получение текста абстрактно, главное логика):

1 вариант

```
<?php
/*
* main.php
*/

require_once 'string.php';

$text_1 = get_string_1();
$text_2 = get_string_2();



<?php
/*
* string.php
*/

function get_string_1() {
    $data = file_get_contents('text_first.txt' );
    return $data;
}

function get_string_2() {
    $data = file_get_contents('text_second.txt' );
    return $data;
}
```

2 вариант

```
<?php
/*
* main.php
*/

require_once 'string.php';

$str = new string();
$text_1 = str->get_1();
$text_2 = str->get_2();



<?php
/*
* string.php
*/
class string {
  function get_1 () {
      $data = file_get_contents('text_first.txt' );
      return $data;
  }

  function get_2 () {
      $data = file_get_contents('text_second.txt' );
      return $data;
  }
}
```

Мой вопрос заключается в выяснении как правильнее можно для примера выполнить эту задачу, и где можно об этом почитать?

Comment: т.е., у вас есть два _(или более)_ текст.файла, и всё что вам требуется, так это вывести их содержимое на страницу?

Comment: какой смысл сравнивать процедурный и ООП подход? каждый имеет право на существование. В любом случае, в обоих этих вариантах имя файла должно быть параметром единственной функции, нет смысл плодить кучу одинакового кода. Если требуется какой то конфиг, то задавайте его в виде ассоциативного массива `[ 'str1' => 'path_to_file1', ...]`

Comment: @Эдуард "получение текста абстрактно, главное логика" данная задача абсолютно абстрактная и к получению текста не имеет отношения, представте какое нибудь другую задачу , какой вариант вы бы использовали и почему?

Comment: @teran данная задача абстрактна, конечно же с получением текста можно поступить намного более рационально

Comment: дак а что вы тогда хотите услышать, какой стиль лучше, процедурный или ООП? на этот вопрос вам четкий ответ никто не даст. ООП код более популярен конечно, и не просто так. чистого процедурного кода сейчас пишется мало, но для маленьких задач, например, смысла в ООП нет вообще. ООП дает намного более гибкий инструментарий, чем чистый процедурное программирование. Но если учесть, что пхп сам по себе очень гибкий язык, то и в процедурном вараинте он может быть весьма удобным.

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров ну если бы у меня была задача - прочитать пару файлов в массив для дальнейших каких-то манипуляций с этими данными, то я бы отсканировал бы директорию с этими файлами, например `glob('*.txt');` и в цикле прочитал бы полученный массив, например `file_get_contents($file_name);` -- всё, и коротко и ясно.

Comment: @teran хотел услышать мнения, то что я услышал от вас мне поможет) Тогда еще к вам вопрос, смешивать процедурный  стиль и ООП насколько допустимо? В частности в пхп

Comment: настолько, насколько это нужно для решения задачи. ВЫ можете выделить некоторый функционал, пометив все соответствующие функции в некоторый файл в процедурном варианте, и можете сделать в принципе то же самое, заключив все это в класс, который тоже будет в отдельном файле.Возможно, если в вашей задаче нет необходимости манипулировать множеством объектов одного вида, которые обладают неким функционалом, то  ООП мб и не нужен. Ведь выходит что в ООП, вы к данным применяете метод, то есть вызываете метод объекта. В процедурном же варианте вы данные передаете в метод, как параметр.